# how to convert java string(Sat, 11 Apr 2015 17:48:17 +0430) to Date

Tags: java, android, date-conversion

Can somebody recommend the best way to convert a string in the format 'Sat, 11 Apr 2015 17:48:17 +0430' to a date in java?

I am doing like this :

```
String date="Sat, 11 Apr 2015 17:48:17 +0430";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date startDate;
        try {
            startDate = df.parse(date);
            String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
            System.out.println(newDateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

error :

```
04-11 13:37:50.956    2186-2200/latest.sports.news W/System.err﹕ java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat, 11 Apr 2015 17:48:17 +0430" (at offset 0)
04-11 13:37:50.956    2186-2200/latest.sports.news W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

update :

How do I convert  `Sat, 11 Apr 2015 17:48:17 +0430` to `04/11/2015`

Comment: "Sat, 11 Apr 2015 17:48:17 +0430" is not in the format "MM/dd/yyyy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String date="Sat, 11 Apr 2015 17:48:17 +0430";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    Date startDate;
    try {
        startDate = df.parse(date);
        String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
        System.out.println(newDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```